# Putty PSFTP output to txt file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, ftp, sftp, putty

I'm trying to identify if a batch file copying files to a server has been sucessful. I am trying to output commands to "output.txt" file but the file is always empty.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client\sfttray.exe" /launch "PSFTP 0.62.0.0" fxx@fosp.nat.xx.com -pw f0sftp -v -b C:\Users\mputFOS.txt  -bc >> C:\Users\output.txt

cd /home/fox
lcd \\office\Server%20Upload%20Files\
put Spf.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

> You'll need to redirect both stdout and stderr.
>
> Just tested it and all the -v stuff goes to stderr.
>
> pscp.exe -v ... >  out.txt redirects stdout to out.txt pscp.exe -v ...
>   2> err.txt redirects stderr to err.txt As a hint
>
> pscp.exe -v ... > both.txt 2<&1

http://whrl.pl/Rckrc7